# How to use GLOBALS in php to post form data

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, global

How do I import GLOBALS variable in the main PHP file so I do not have to change project name every time in the src?

Comment: can you post the full contents of index.php, including the `<?php` and `?>` tags and the include statement?

Comment: @Luke posted as needed

Comment: @Luke I followed your advise and somehow made it work. But now am in bigger trouble http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39984235/use-global-variables-to-dynamically-change-url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I made a config.php file and declared GLOBALS['project_name'] = 'project_name'; in it.

When calling this, I only call it using $project_name;

Answer (score 1):

```
name = $GLOBALS['project_name']
```

This is the problem. You have included php code inside the html without telling php to process it. You can try it like this:

```
<input type = "text" name="<?php echo($GLOBALS['project_name']) ?>" id = "project_name" class = "form-control" placeholder="Enter Project Name"  value = "">
```

However, as you have it written you probably don't need to use the $GLOBALS superglobal variable at all, as everything is being executed in the same scope (you have no functions). You could simply have this:

**config.php**

```
<?php
$project_name = 'test';
?>
```

**index.php**

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');
?>
<form action="upload.php" method="post">
  <h3 class="text-center">If Project Name does not exist, add new one below.</h3>     
  <div class = "form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="project_name">Project Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <input type = "text" name="<?php echo($project_name) ?>" id="project_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Project Name"  value= "">
    </div>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**upload.php**

```
<?php
include_once('config.php');

$project_name = $_POST[$project_name];
$version = $_POST['version'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$data = "INSERT INTO demo VALUES(NULL, '$project_name', '$version', '$description', '$path')";

$download_data = "SELECT demo_id, demo_name, demo_version, demo_details, file 
                      FROM demo
                      WHERE demo_name = '$project_name'
                      AND demo_version = '$version'";

?>
```

note: this last section of upload.php is dangerous for a production environment, you should read about "sql injection" and "prepared statements" if you want to actually run this code on an sql server.

**explanation of $GLOBALS**

I'm not sure what research you have done on this superglobal but i would suggest reading the php.net page on scope: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

This code snippet demonstrates a correct usage:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function Sum()
{
    $GLOBALS['b'] = $GLOBALS['a'] + $GLOBALS['b'];
} 

Sum();
echo $b;
?>
```

In this case the output would be 3. If the code was written without using $GLOBALS:

```
<?php
$a = 1;
$b = 2;

function Sum()
{
    $b = $a + $b;
} 

Sum();
echo $b;
?>
```

The output would be 1. The variables $a and $b within the sum() function in this example are "local variables" - they are only in *scope* within the sum() function and are different memory locations (despite having the same names) to the $a and $b variables that are assigned the values of 1 and 2 respectively. So the sum operation happens, but it does not alter the value of the $b variable being output by the echo statement (as the $b within sum() is not the same as the $b outside of the function).

Comment: Hi this still send project name as empty

Comment: I actually forgot to put the form/submit elements in so you shouldn't have even been able to submit it (have edited index.php now). You do need to have all the files saved in the same directory. If the project name is empty in the HTML output from index.php then the include must be failing or it can't find the config.php file. Here is an example of index.php showing that the "name" attribute in the HTML form is not blank: http://ideone.com/wcev5c

Answer (score -1):

If you declare a Global Variable you can easily use it as variable like this:

```
$GLOBALS['project_name'] = 'test';
echo $project_name; //test
```

In your case:

```
<?php    
global $project_name; 
?>   
    <div class = "form-group">
        <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for ="<?php echo $project_name; ?>">Project Name:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8"><input type = "text" name ="<?php echo $project_name;?>" id ="<?php echo $project_name; ?>" class = "form-control" placeholder="Enter Project Name"  value = ""></div></div>
```

Last Update Your PHP Code:

```
global $project_name;
$project = $_POST[$project_name];
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: you never set the value of $GLOBALS['project_name'] or $project_name within the second code snippet - you'll need to include the code from the first snippet within the second. Put another way: $GLOBALS values do not persist across calls to separate scripts.