# Use Global Variables to dynamically change URL

Tags: php, html, mysql, .htaccess, global

So this is going to be really hard to explain,

I have an A folder and I have a B folder. I am using a common database for both of them.

Both folder have following files, inside each of them => config.php, index.php, upload.php, control_admin.php, admin.php and view.php. There are some basic database, CSS and JS files which B shares with A(not of any problem).

Now A is for project A and B is for project B.

for each of the projects, I have URLs => a.example.com & b.example.com

At a.example.com/index.php I upload an image file which characteristics like project_name = Apple Version = 1.

At b.example.com/index.php I upload an image file which characteristics like project_name = Banana Version = 1.

These images are uploaded to image folders in A and B respectively.

Now to view these images, I could have gone to

a.example.com\view.php?$version=1 and could have seen the pic.

similarly for b.example.com

I have modified this in .htaccess to make a friendly URL which takes me to

a.example.com\1 and displays the image as required.

Now comes the problem. Each of the view.php file have the following image link

```
<img src = "<?php echo     "http://".$GLOBALS['url']."".$GLOBALS['img_folder']."/".$new ?>" style = 'margin: 0px auto; display:block; max-width: 100%;height: auto;'>
```

I take these global variables from config.php of each file.

For A:

```
<?php $GLOBALS['project_name'] = 'Apple';?>

<?php $GLOBALS['url'] = 'a.example.com/'?>

<?php $GLOBALS["folder"] = 'FolderA'; ?>

<?php $GLOBALS['img_folder'] = 'AppleImages'; ?>
```

For B:

```
<?php $GLOBALS['project_name'] = 'Banana';?>

<?php $GLOBALS['url'] = 'b.example.com/'?>

<?php $GLOBALS["folder"] = 'FolderB'; ?>

<?php $GLOBALS['img_folder'] = 'BananaImages'; ?>
```

Now the issue is, if I upload version 1 of A and then version 1 of B and then I go to the link which is friendly URL from a.example.com/1 or b.example.com/1... I cannot see the one at A after I upload a file at B. Because the URL is hard pointing at B as it is the recent upload in the same database.

What can I do to the URL to make sure, if I upload to a.example.com and then to b.example.com, files with same version... I can see both images at their respective URLs

a.example.com/2 and b.example.com/2

I hope I made sense. Thanks in advance.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B5nDbj-RhZJMa3drNFlfRzVaLXc?usp=sharing

Comment: what is `$new` in the image link?

Comment: @RyanVincent the upload_id is automatically generated or do we have ti enter it?

Comment: You would have to generate it. But this solution would be unmanageable with many uploads. Your solution is probably a similar line of thinking - but add a column to the table where you store upload information and store the project name in each upload record, so you can look up the correct file name using the version number and the project name. But without telling us what `$new` is and where it comes from, it's hard to say why it's failing.

Comment: @Luke Hi I have put the folders on drive, please see main question.

Comment: $new is the basename of the attached file.

Comment: I suspected as such. So the basename of the attached file in project A with version = 1 is different to the basename of the attached file in project B with version = 1. And the image is not shown in project A, after uploading an image to project B because the place you are storing the basename for project A is over-written when you upload the file for project B. So again, *how* are you retrieving the basename into the variable $new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked through the google drive link you provided.

**view.php : line 64**

```
$project_name_download_form = $_GET['project_name'];
```

Unless you are accessing view.php with a url like this:

```
a.example.com\view.php?version=1&project_name=apple
```

Your `$project_name_download_form` will have an empty string value and your SQL query becomes:

```
SELECT demo_id, demo_name, demo_version, demo_details, file 
                      FROM demo
                      WHERE  demo_name = ''
                      AND  demo_version = '1'
```

So 2 actions, change line 64 to:

```
$project_name_download_form = $GLOBALS['project_name'];
```

And then check the database directly to make sure the demo_name column has values being set in it (and not just blank).

Comment: Using $GLOBALS is nasty because it's settable from all user input like GET, POST and COOKIE @siddparkar